# Java regex for string which was prefixed with @

Tags: java, regex

Say I have the following string

```
"@apple @banna @? example@test.com"
```

now I want to make it

```
"apple banna ? example@test.com"
```

What should be my regular expression be to remove "@" symbols without effecting email addresses?

Comment: I tired str.replaceAll("@apple", "apple"); and str.replaceFirst("@", "")

Comment: You're going to need to be more clear about what characters you expect after the `@` that you want to remove since you don't want to remove `@`s in email addresses. I'm assuming that you aren't literally going to have 'apple' and 'banna` in your strings. Does the @ always appear at the beginning of a word, as above?

Comment: Dont forget you have to do `str = str.replaceFirst("@","");` as a String is immutable the replaceFirst method returns a new string rather than modifying an existing String.

Comment: Updated my answer after your question update

Comment: I think that my answer below has what you are looking for. It checks to make sure that the @ is the first character of the word, and that it is not a character by itself.

Comment: how does it fail for an email addresses? "valid@email.com" is changed to "validemail.com", or "valid email.com" if yuo replace with space

Comment: @mabn He doesn't want it to replace the @ in an email address, and it does, hence the failing.

Answer (score 3):

I think this will work.

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<!\S)@(?=\S+)");
```

Here's what this does:

```
(?<!\S)     // Checks to make sure that the @ is preceded by a whitespace
            // character, or is the beginning of the string. This exists to make sure we're not in an email.
@           // Literal @
(?=\S+)     // Makes sure that something besides whitespace follows.
```

Here are some quick tests: http://fiddle.re/2vmt

Comment: Very interesting website. I don't do regex often, but I will be soon.

Comment: @SaviourSelf If you liked that one you'll also like http://www.regex101.com/. It actually breaks down the regex for you and tells you what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

This question has changed significantly since its original posting. My original answer, although correct for the question as originally posed, is no longer correct.

This code will do it:

```
String noStrayAts = input.replaceAll("(?<=\\s)@", "");
```

---

Fyi, here is my previous answer:

Since both input and output are Strings, and the thing being removed does not require a regex, you simply need:

```
String noAts = input.replace("@", "");
```

Comment: This will remove all @ symbols in a string, not just the first one

Comment: fails for valid email address sorry.

Comment: where did you say anything about valid email addresses?  explain better in the question and people would be able to help you better

Comment: What do you mean exactly? This code deluvers what the examples in your question require. Please give sample input and output so I understand what you mean

Comment: @KailuaBum He did say 'string which was <b>prefixed</b> by @' in the title, though you're right, he should have put it in the question body. An email address isn't really prefixed by @, and therefore shouldn't be affected by the regex. My solution should work. See below.

Comment: It should be noted that this answer is incorrect since it is not valid for email addresses, as OP mentioned.

Comment: @Michael fixed in line with the new version of the question

Comment: @Bohemian If the string just happens to have an `@` all alone, I don't think he's going to want to remove it. Also, Based off of his past questions I don't think he's going to accept an answer...

Comment: looks like we are close enough fails for a @ n

Answer (score 0):

```
String fruit = fruit.replaceAll("@", " ");
```

Answer (score -1):

one way of doing this is following :

```
str.replaceAll("@apple", "apple"); 
str.replaceAll("@banna", "banna"); 
str.replaceAll("@?", "?");
```

Comment: this will only work on the example in the questions.  this would not work for email addresses

Comment: And that third line would convert `@?` to `???`.  Perhaps instead of `replaceAll()` you meant to use `replace()`, which treats the search term as a literal string, not as a regex.